# Duplicate list edits should be shown on the question itself

Tags: feature-request, edits, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Editing the list of duplicates on a question bumps said question and appears as a revision in the questions revision history, there is no indication on the question page itself though.

So this is what you see on the homepage, with the user and timestamp of the edit:

> [image: Bumped question]

This is what you see in the revision history:

> [image: Duplicate list edit revision]

On the question itself... nothing:

> [image: No revision]

Seeing a post was edited on the homepage then opening it to see nothing has changed is pretty confusing. This is, as far as I know (?), now the only thing that will bump a question with no indication on the question itself (community bumps used to; they now have a notice).

Comment: I sort of support the other solution more: Don't bump questions when their duplicates list is edited. I can't think of any case where information that the list was just edited would be actionable. If it must be displayed somewhere it should probably just be in the 10k tools page (e.g. "recently edited duplicate lists"), but even that I can't see as particularly useful.

Comment: @JasonC personally I think it's pretty important that someone sees the edit, I'm not a fan of users being able to single handedly edit stuff like that with zero visibility... If that was the case though, sure, leave it off the Q page (I'm all for consistency, whatever happens).

Comment: There *is* one very specific case related to this that is slightly weird, though: If somebody edits the dupe list on a post that was *never* edited, there's no edit card, and the only way to see who did the dupe list edit is to manually enter the revision list URL in the address bar ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963794)). I'm not entirely sure what's actionable about that, but it *is* a UX inconsistency.